# Application Loader freeze, but status "Waiting for Review"

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I have just tried to uploaded an app through the Application Loader, but it froze in the middle of the upload (the percentage were in the middle and the window was not responding).
However, on iTunes Connects I now see that the status is "Waiting for Review".

Is it possible that the status changed even though the binary didn't upload completely?
Or the upload did complete and just my view was stuck?

Finally the question is if I should reject the binary and upload again, or safely continue with the review.

Comment: I would reject the binary and try again.

Comment: To get to the "Waiting for review" stage it must have passed the verification stage so I believe the app was uploaded correctly. But if it were my app I'd retry anyway to save time in case it did go wrong.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple's rejection policies. See also: [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's in "Waiting for Review" you can change the binary at any time, without losing your line in the app review queue, so, if you want to be sure, you can change it without any problems.

Comment: How do I change the binary? Should I click "Reject this Binary"?

Comment: yes, after that you just upload the new one; https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf

Answer (score 1):

While "Waiting for Review", When you resubmit your binary by rejecting your old, **you lose your line in the queue.**

> If you reject your binary, the status of your app will change to
>   Developer Rejected. When you resubmit your binary, the review process
>   starts over from the beginning.

From p. 83 in http://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf

Demz answer is not correct (I don't have the privilege to comment it).

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely reject your application, and re-upload it. If it turns out that nothings wrong, then no problem but if something is wrong, you may end up getting rejected by Apple.

In addition to this, you may want to consider using the new application loader built into Xcode, I've found using it to be a much more streamlined process.